# Reusing buffers for a loop-skewed stencil

Tags: c, performance, nested-loops, cpu-cache

I am trying to optimise a stencil operation, which takes an array A of length n, and then does the operation

A[i] = f(A[i - 1], A[i], A[i + 1])

for a number of iterations. We can implement this with only 2n memory by swapping buffers like so:

```
/* n is the length of the array, m is the number of iterations. */
void stencil(size_t n, int m, double *in, double *out)
{
    for (int t = 0; t < m; t++) {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
            out[i] = f(in[i - 1], in[i], in[i + 1]);
        }
        if (t != m - 1) {
            double *temp = in;
            in = out;
            out = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

This is cache-unfriendly, because we iterate through the entire array a number of times.
We can optimise this using polyhedral techniques, such as page 8 of https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19910023530/downloads/19910023530.pdf . However, this introduces an extra dimension, so it has O(nm) memory usage instead of O(n). I want to use this technique with buffer swapping. I think this is possible, because taking a skewed square/inner block (x-axis is the array, y-axis is time)

```
. . x .
  . . . .
    o . . .
```

we do not need o anymore by the time we calculate x, so it's fine to overwrite. However, it does not work in my program, see below (it includes some code for testing and timing).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MIN(a, b) (((a) < (b)) ? a : b)
#define MAX(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? a : b)

inline double f(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return 0.33 * a + 0.5 * b + 0.25 * c;
}

void init(double *arr, double value, size_t length)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        arr[i] = value;
    }
}

/* in has to be initialised, writes the output to out. 
 * Returns the number of flops performed. */
size_t stencil(size_t n, int m, double *in, double *out)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for (int t = 0; t < m; t++) {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
            out[i] = f(in[i - 1], in[i], in[i + 1]);
            count += 5;
        }
        if (t != m - 1) {
            double *temp = in;
            in = out;
            out = temp;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

size_t stencilOpt(size_t n, int m, double *in, double *out)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    int bt = 10;
    size_t br = 100;

    for (int t0 = 0; t0 < m; t0 += bt) {
        for (size_t r0 = t0 + 1; r0 < t0 + n - 1; r0 += br) {
            for (int t = t0; t < MIN(m, t0 + bt - 1); t++) {
                for (size_t r = MAX(r0, t + 1); r < MIN(t + n - 1, r0 + br - 1); r++) {
                    out[r - t] = f(in[r - t - 1], in[r - t], in[r - t + 1]); 
                    printf("%zu\n", r - t);
                    count += 5;
                }
                double *temp = in;
                in = out;
                out = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Please specify 2 arguments (n, iterations).\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t n = atoll(argv[1]);
    int m = atoi(argv[2]);

    /* Pointers of type double[n], so a dereference [i] adds i * n * sizeof(double)
     * bytes to this pointer and then dereferences, aka i rows further. */
    double *in = malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double *out = malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    init(in, 1.0, n);

    time_t start = clock();
    size_t count = stencil(n, m, in, out);
    time_t end  = clock();
    double duration = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Check: %lf\n", out[100]);
    printf("Time %lfs, n %zu, m %d, %lf Gflops/s\n", duration, n, m, 
            5.0 * (n - 2) * m / 1000000000.0 / duration);
    printf("Actual flops: %zu\n", count);

    init(in, 1.0, n);
    start = clock();
    count = stencilOpt(n, m, in, out);
    end = clock();
    duration = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Check: %lf\n", out[100]);
    printf("Time %lfs, n %zu, m %d, %lf Gflops/s\n", duration, n, m, 
            5.0 * (n - 2) * m / 1000000000.0 / duration);
    printf("Actual flops: %zu\n", count);

    free(in);
    free(out);
}
```

Comment: @JérômeRichard Depends on the application, but the bigger the better, with n >> iterations because you are iteratively approximating a function on a certain domain, with n being the number of sample points. For example n as large as you can fit into RAM, and a few hundred iterations is pretty typical I would say.

Comment: How big are `n` and `iterations` in practice? Caches are pretty big nowadays. Thus, if `n` is smaller than the L1 cache size divided by 16, then cache-based optimization are useless. Since x86-64 CPU L1 cache are usually 32-48 KiB, this means a maximum `n` of 2000~3000. The L2 is a bit slower but it is usually >=8 times bigger. When `n` start to be big, you can use multiple cores so the sum of the L2 cache (typically few MB, so `n ~ 100_000`). Besides, did you check the code is bounded by caches and is properly vectorized by the compiler?

Comment: What about using existing tools? AFAIR, there are academic tools like for example PATUS, Pochoir, Halide, etc. (there are many DSL and autotuners for that and there are also few code generators). AFAIK, some are high-optimized. It might be simpler and faster to use them (not to mention it avoid reinventing the wheel ;) ).